# Mocking Issue with apollo client in Jest+React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am facing issues with mocking Graphql API using apollo mock provider. I have followed official documentation to mock the apollo client.

I have called one graphQl api in the useEffect

```
 const fetchUserList = () => {
    client
      .query({
        query: GET_USERS,
        fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
      })
      .then((response: any) => {
        setUsers(response.data.getUsers);
      })
      .catch((err: ApolloError) => {
        ShowSnackbar(
          "Failed to fetch Users" + err.message,
          false,
          enqueueSnackbar
        );
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserList();
  }, []);

export const GET_USERS = gql`
  query getUsers {
    getUsers {
      id
      firstName
      lastName
      emailId
      mobilePhone
      lastLogin
      lastUpdated
      role {
        roleId
        roleName
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

I am trying to mock this Graphql api call in jest as shown below:

```
const mocks = [
    {
       request: {
         query: GET_USERS
       },
       result: {
         data: {
           getUsers: [
             {
              id: 36,
               firstName: "ABC",
              lastName: "XYZ",
              emailId: "abc.xyz.ext@pqr.com",
              mobilePhone: "+91 77888",
               lastLogin: "2023-07-31T04:47:21",
               lastUpdated: "2023-07-21T11:50:14",
              role:{
                roleId:1,
                 roleName:"ADMIN"
               }
             },
           ],
         },
       }
 }
   ];

 
  test("Check if USer Management is rendered correctly", async () => {
    // ARRANGE
    //const mockSpy = mocks[0].result;
    render(
      <SnackbarProvider>
        <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
          <UserManagement />
        </MockedProvider>
      </SnackbarProvider>
    );
```

But when I see in the test case coverage the mocking is not successful as shown below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEBo1.png)

I want to mock this Graphql Api call. Please suggest